# A category of type-changing substitutions

Tags: haskell, programming-languages, agda, type-theory

## The setup

Consider a type of terms parameterized over a type of function symbols `node`
and a type of variables `var`:

```hs
data Term node var
  = VarTerm !var
  | FunTerm !node !(Vector (Term node var))
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

instance Functor (Term node) where
  fmap f (VarTerm var)  = VarTerm (f var)
  fmap f (FunTerm n cs) = FunTerm n (Vector.map (fmap f) cs)

instance Monad (Term node) where
  pure = VarTerm
  join (VarTerm term) = term
  join (FunTerm n cs) = FunTerm n (Vector.map join cs)
```

This is a useful type, since we encode open terms with `Term node Var`,
closed terms with `Term node Void`, and contexts with `Term node ()`.

The goal is to define a type of substitutions on `Term`s in the most pleasant
possible way. Here's a first stab:

```hs
newtype Substitution (node ∷ Type) (var ∷ Type)
  = Substitution { fromSubstitution ∷ Map var (Term node var) }
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

Now let's define some auxiliary values related to `Substitution`:

```hs
subst ∷ Substitution node var → Term node var → Term node var
subst s (VarTerm var)  = fromMaybe (MkVarTerm var)
                         (Map.lookup var (fromSubstitution s))
subst s (FunTerm n ts) = FunTerm n (Vector.map (subst s) ts)

identity ∷ Substitution node var
identity = Substitution Map.empty

-- Laws:
--
-- 1. Unitality:
--    ∀ s ∷ Substitution n v → s ≡ (s ∘ identity) ≡ (identity ∘ s)
-- 2. Associativity:
--    ∀ a, b, c ∷ Substitution n v → ((a ∘ b) ∘ c) ≡ (a ∘ (b ∘ c))
-- 3. Monoid action:
--    ∀ x, y ∷ Substitution n v → subst (y ∘ x) ≡ (subst y . subst x)
(∘) ∷ (Ord var)
    ⇒ Substitution node var
    → Substitution node var
    → Substitution node var
s1 ∘ s2 = Substitution
          (Map.unionWith
           (λ _ _ → error "this should never happen")
           (Map.map (subst s1) (fromSubstitution s2))
           ((fromSubstitution s1) `Map.difference` (fromSubstitution s2)))
```

Clearly, `(Substitution n v, ∘, identity)` is a monoid (ignoring the `Ord`
constraint on `∘`) and `(Term n v, subst)` is a monoid action of
`Substitution n v`.

Now suppose that we want to make this scheme encode substitutions
*that change the variable type*. This would look like some type `SubstCat`
that satisfies the module signature below:

```hs
data SubstCat (node ∷ Type) (domainVar ∷ Type) (codomainVar ∷ Type)
  = … ∷ Type

subst ∷ SubstCat node dom cod → Term node dom → Term node cod

identity ∷ SubstCat node var var

(∘) ∷ (Ord v1, Ord v2, Ord v3)
    → SubstCat node v2 v3
    → SubstCat node v1 v2
    → SubstCat node v1 v3
```

This is almost a Haskell `Category`, but for the `Ord` constraints on `∘`.
You might think that if `(Substitution n v, ∘, identity)` was a monoid before,
and `subst` was a monoid action before, then `subst` should now be a category
action, but in point of fact category actions are just functors (in this case,
a functor from a subcategory of Hask to another subcategory of Hask).

Now there are some properties we'd hope would be true about `SubstCat`:

1. `SubstCat node var Void` should be the type of ground substitutions.
2. `SubstCat Void var var` should be the type of flat substitutions.
3. `instance (Eq node, Eq dom, Eq cod) ⇒ Eq (SubstCat node dom cod)`
   should exist (as well as similar instances for `Ord` and `Show`).
4. It should be possible to compute the domain variable set, the image term
   set, and the introduced variable set, given a `SubstCat node dom cod`.
5. The operations I have described should be about as fast/space-efficient
   as their equivalents in the `Substitution` implementation above.

The simplest possible approach to writing `SubstCat` would be to simply
generalize `Substitution`:

```hs
newtype SubstCat (node ∷ Type) (dom ∷ Type) (cod ∷ Type)
  = SubstCat { fromSubstCat ∷ Map dom (Term node cod) }
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work because when we run `subst` it may be the
case that the term we are running substitution on contains variables that are
not in the domain of the `Map`. We could get away with this in `Substitution`
since `dom ~ cod`, but in `SubstCat` we have no way to deal with these
variables.

My next attempt was to deal with this issue by also including a function of
type `dom → cod`:

```hs
data SubstCat (node ∷ Type) (dom ∷ Type) (cod ∷ Type)
  = SubstCat
    !(Map dom (Term node cod))
    !(dom → cod)
```

This causes a few problems, however. Firstly, since `SubstCat` now contains a
function, it can no longer have `Eq`, `Ord`, or `Show` instances. We cannot
simply ignore the `dom → cod` field when comparing for equality, since the
semantics of substitution change depending on its value. Secondly, it is now
no longer the case that `SubstCat node var Void` represents a type of ground
substitutions; in fact, `SubstCat node var Void` is *uninhabited*!

Érdi Gergő suggested on Facebook that I use the following definition:

```hs
newtype SubstCat (node ∷ Type) (dom ∷ Type) (cod ∷ Type)
  = SubstCat (dom → Term node cod)
```

This is certainly a fascinating prospect. There is an obvious category for this
type: the Kleisli category given by the `Monad` instance on `Term node`. I am
not sure if this actually corresponds to the usual notion of substitution
composition, however. Unfortunately, this representation cannot have instances
for `Eq` et al. and I suspect it could be very inefficient in practice, since
in the best case it will end up being a tower of closures of height `Θ(n)`,
where `n` is the number of insertions. It also doesn't allow computation of the
domain variable set.

## The question

Is there a sensible type for `SubstCat` that fits my requirements? Can you prove
that one does not exist? If I give up having correct instances of `Eq`, `Ord`,
and `Show`, is it possible?

Comment: The answer I would’ve written, “it’s the Kleisli category of the `Term` monad”, has already been given below, so I’ll just point you towards some further reading: [_Type- and Scope-Safe Programs and Their Proofs_](https://gallais.github.io/pdf/cpp2017.pdf)

Comment: “in the best case it will end up being a tower of closures” - the function doesn’t have to be built by composition. Nothing stopping you from just doing a `Map` lookup inside the function

Comment: How do you understand that `Term node ()` is a context?  If I unravel that definition, I get a tree of `node`s. How is that a context?

Comment: When I say a "context", I mean that in the sense of "a term with exactly one free variable". Like an evaluation context; not like a typing context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There is an obvious category for this type: the Kleisli category given
>   by the Monad instance on Term node. I am not sure if this actually
>   corresponds to the usual notion of substitution composition, however.

It does correspond to that, and it's an all-around correct definition of parallel substitution for well-scoped terms. You may note that this substitution is *total*; this is a requirement if you want term substitution to be total, i. e. that it's a functor from the category of substitutions (**Subst**) to **Set**. For a simple example for why partial substitutions don't work, if you have an empty `SubstCat node () Void`, then you would have to invent arbitrary closed terms when hitting `VarTerm ()` in `subst` - and closed terms don't even exist if you choose `Void` for `node`.

Hence, if you have `Map dom (Term node cod)` then you have partial term substitution, i. e. a functor from **Subst** to the Kleisli category for `Maybe` (disregarding for now formal complications from the `Ord` constraints):

```
type Subst node i j = Map i (Term node j)

subst :: Ord i => Subst node i j -> Term node i -> Maybe (Term node j)
subst sub (VarTerm x)    = Map.lookup x sub
subst sub (FunTerm f ts) = FunTerm f <$> traverse (subst sub) ts
```

---

Now, total term substitution along with your 1-5 desiderata for `SubstCat` is possible, but not with the current kinds for `SubstCat` and `Term`. As I mentioned, in this case substitutions must be total, but currently we can just have `SubstCat node dom cod` with some infinite `dom`, which makes equality of substitutions undecidable.

So let's switch to a more precise formalization, which contains only what we care about here. We have well-scoped untyped terms, and we assume that terms are finite and live in finite variable contexts.

Untyped terms imply that only sizes of variable contexts matter. So, **Subst** has natural numbers as objects:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Terms are indexed by `n :: Nat`, containing `n` possible values for variables:

```
-- {-# language TypeInType, GADTs, TypeFamilies, ScopedTypeVariables,
--           FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, RankNTypes,
--           TypeApplications, StandaloneDeriving #-}

data Fin n where
  FZ :: Fin (S n)
  FS :: Fin n -> Fin (S n)
deriving instance Eq (Fin n)
deriving instance Ord (Fin n)
deriving instance Show (Fin n)

data Term node (n :: Nat) where
  VarTerm :: !(Fin n) -> Term node n
  FunTerm :: !node -> !(Vector (Term node n)) -> Term node n

deriving instance Eq node => Eq (Term node n)
deriving instance Ord node => Ord (Term node n)
deriving instance Show node => Show (Term node n)
```

Substitutions (morphisms) are vectors of terms:

```
data Vec a n where
  Nil  :: Vec a Z
  (:>) :: a -> Vec a n -> Vec a (S n)
infixr 5 :>

deriving instance Eq a => Eq (Vec a n)
deriving instance Ord a => Ord (Vec a n)
deriving instance Show a => Show (Vec a n)

type Subst node i j = Vec (Term node j) i
```

Term substitution is as follows:

```
subst :: Subst node i j -> Term node i -> Term node j
subst (t :> _ ) (VarTerm FZ)     = t
subst (_ :> ts) (VarTerm (FS x)) = subst ts (VarTerm x)
subst sub       (FunTerm f ts)   = FunTerm f (Vector.map (subst sub) ts)
```

Composition is just pointwise `subst`:

```
comp :: Subst node i j -> Subst node j k -> Subst node i k
comp Nil       sub2 = Nil
comp (t :> ts) sub2 = subst sub2 t :> comp ts sub2
```

Identity substitution is not so easy. We need to dispatch on a type-level `Nat`. For this, we use here a type class; [`singletons`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) would be a heavier but more principled solution. The implementation itself is also a bit mind-bending. It makes use of the fact that `Subst node n m` is isomorphic to `(Fin n -> Term node m)`. In fact, we could just use the functional representation all the time, but then the `Eq, Ord and Show` instances would still effectively need the backwards conversion, and we would not have the spacetime boundedness guarantees of (strict) vectors.

```
class Tabulate n where
  tabulate :: (Fin n -> Term node m) -> Subst node n m

instance Tabulate Z where
  tabulate f = Nil

instance Tabulate n => Tabulate (S n) where
  tabulate f = f FZ :> tabulate (f . FS)

idSubst :: Tabulate n => Subst node n n
idSubst = tabulate VarTerm
```

That's it! Proofs of category laws for `Subst` and functor laws for `subst` are left as exercise.

---

PS: I note that in literature and formal Agda/Coq developments, `Nat` indices of `Subst` are usually in swapped order, and `subst` has *contravariant* action.

Comment: "indices of `Subst` are usually in swapped order" -- do you know why this is the case?

Comment: @user3237465 A term is a single thing in a context, a substitution is zero or more things in a context. This suggests notation such as Γ ⊢ t : A and Γ ⊢ σ : Δ, or people use (Γ ⇒ Δ) or (Sub Γ Δ) etc. Also, if you take the standard set-semantics, ⟦ Sub Γ Δ ⟧ is ⟦ Γ ⟧ → ⟦ Δ ⟧, and I don't know of any semantics when the (generalized) arrow goes in the other direction. With polymorphic and dependent TT, the arrow generally *can't* go in the other direction because of A possibly depending on Γ in Γ ⊢ t : A.

Answer (score 6):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.MemoTrie
import Control.Category.Constrained

newtype SubstCat node dom cod = SubstCat (dom :->: Term node cod)

instance Category (SubstCat node) where
  type Object (SubstCat node) a = HasTrie a
  id = SubstCat (trie VarTerm)
  SubstCat f . SubstCat g = SubstCat $ fmap (untrie f =<<) g
```

The [memo-trie type `:->:`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie-0.6.9/docs/Data-MemoTrie.html#t::-45--62-:) is basically a map type, but the mappings are always total. I.e., they are proper functions, but in a memory-fixed representation – no closures needed. This only works for types that are not only orderable but also completely enumeratable, which is what the [`HasTrie` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie-0.6.9/docs/Data-MemoTrie.html#t:HasTrie) expresses; thus we can't define an instance for `Control.Category.Category` but we can define an instance for [its constrainable pendant](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.3.1.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:Category).